File input allowing multiple files of one type and single file of another
The title says it all, I want a file input to allow to pick only one .gif file and several .jpg files.
Is that possible? I didn't find it in the specification but maybe I'm missing something.

No, you can't do that. See here and here for more details. You can use two input fields though... One that accepts only one gif file and the other that accepts multiple jpg files.
